# error: ISO C forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++, c, random, compiler-errors

I am brand new to programming and I have just finished reading the Book C for Dummies by Dan Gookin. But I thought I am trying to make tiny programs to get a feel of the language.

I learned that there is a random counter in C (which is not that random), and apparently using the computers internal clock helps making the random counter more random. I saw a code example in the book and it work when I want to printf() random numbers in a grid. But now I would like the program to limit it to only 3 numbers but instead of printing out the numbers in digits I'm interested in learning how to have the computer return printf() functions in a random manner. It doesn't have to be printf() it really can be any function, but this seems to be the easiest way to check.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int rnd(int range);
void seedrnd(void);

int main()
{
    int x;

    seedrnd();
    for(x=0;x<1;x++)
        // printf("%i\t" ,rnd(3));
        if(seedrnd==0)
            printf("Zero");
        else if(seedrnd==1)
            printf("One");
        else
            printf("Two");
    return(0);
}

int rnd(int range)
{
    int r;

    r=rand()%range;
    return(r);
}

void seedrnd(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
}
```

Comment: `if(seedrnd==0)` what does this mean to you?

Comment: Also, your `for` loop is useless, unless you decreased the max for our benifit

Comment: These *X for Dummies* series give me chills

Answer (score 2):

You put `seedrnd` (a pointer to `seedrnd` function) instead of a call to `rnd(int)`. You meant to call a function, not to use its name, in comparison expressions:

```
for(x=0;x<1;x++) {
    int r = rnd(3); // Call rnd(3)
    printf("%i\t", r);
    if(r==0) // Use r, not seedrnd
        printf("Zero");
    else if(r==1)
        printf("One");
    else
        printf("Two");
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you, I also had to declare "int r;" above the main() I first got the error int r not declared, this is all very new to me, but I am slowly catching on.